# WMS bounded overlay with OpenLayers and GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I'm trying to design a heatmap overlay bounded within four given coordinates with OpenLayers using WMS protocol to communicate with my GeoServer instance, where my data and SLD heatmap description reside.
I can basically do it but I incur in two problems I'd like to fix:

1. I have to set "singleTile: false" in the WMS options, and this causes the heatmap to be recomputed for each sent tile, and thus have some discontinuity.
   [Here is an example of what I mean with discontinuity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydBSN.png)
2. I select bounds using maxExtent option, which causes entire tiles to be displayed, even if I'm only interested in a small portion of the selected tile.

Here is my code from the javascript side:

```js
  format = 'image/png';
  heatmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"Rainfall", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/postgis/wms",
{
  LAYERS: 'postgis:rainfall',
  format: format,
  transparent: true
},
{
  singleTile: false,
  visibility: true,
  buffer: 0,
  maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-15000000, -6000000, -8000000, 2000000),
  isBaseLayer: false
}
```

My questions are:
What is the right way to do what I'm trying to do?
Is it possible to use WMS protocol to do that?, should I do it at a lower level(maybe in the SLD)?